# Selecting cells next to certain cell

Tags: xpath

I am trying to follow urls on a web page using automation process, but I'm stuck on infinite loop as a result of using invalid xpath selector.

Here's an example table:

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td><a href="#">...</a></td>
   <td><a href="#">4</a></td>
   <td><a href="#">5</a></td>
   <td><span>6</span></td>
   <td><a href="#">7</a></td>
   <td><a href="#">8</a></td>
   <td><a href="#">9</a></td>
   <td><a href="#">10</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How Can I select all the cells that are after the cell with no url, I mean getting cells from 7 to 10 (without supplying the position() manually) as it's variable position & the table shown above is for demonstration purpose only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use following-sibling to get following siblings/cells:

```
/table//tr/td[not(a)]/following-sibling::td
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use this xpath as well:

```
//span/../following-sibling::td/a
```

which means- find the span, then look for its parent, then look for the parent's following siblings and find its children 'a'